# instance of an object

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

Trying to connect to database by

```
Tools > Connect Database.
```

[image]

Select the connection

[image]

[image]

And as soon as i select one of the connection, Error:

[image]

I am not sure what is causing this. To try to fix this i have uninstall everything, cleaned registry, wiped my computer (re-imaged) etc... I have yet to figure out what is causing this. Since i am using same thing on Laptop and it works fine.  But on desktop i have been having this issues since Monday. I finally gave up and had to come ask to rescue.

Thank you for any help.

EDIT: I have also tried /safemode = No luck.
      I have also tried uninstall/disable ext. and plugins but No luck.

EDIT2: This is what i get when i try to connect to sql server. Even though test connection comes back successful, it some reason doesn't like it.
[image]

EDIT3: Same thing happens when i try to use SQL Server Data Tools.

Comment: What kind of database are you trying to connect to?

Comment: I have tried sql and it gives me an error. Also tried connecting to AS400 gives me that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by removing `</DbProviderFactories>` from machine.config

File location: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config`
`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config`

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Hope this helps to other.